# no sound alert to let me know i have a text message received

Tags: sms, notifications, audio

I can't seem to get an audible sound when text message received.

Comment: Any more details would be useful - stock message app or another?

Comment: I have the sam problem using Samsung Galaxy S2.
Had sound tones from soundboard apps, now nothing, even when using tones that previously worked.
I don't have an SMS APP just whats on the phone.
When chosing a tone from the list they play fine, but not when receiving a message.
Unsure exactly what was done before the loss of sound.

Answer (score 5):

Things to check include:

- You have configured a sound for your SMS app
- The notification volume is reasonable (in line with the ringer volume is probably good)
- You don't have either silent or vibrate silent mode selected
- You've enabled notifications in your SMS app